# Astrophysics about the constancy of light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction

I'm always confused when light ray travel from rarer to denser medium its velocity decreases and then how is the speed of light constant.

Comment: The speed of light is constant **in a vacuum**. It's speed can change in varying mediums.

Comment: I believe it is constant but travels farther through the medium.